# Optimizing an embedded linux system's root file system size

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded

I am working on an embedded system which runs on linux. To reduce the boot time of the product (It is an IP net camera) I would like to **reduce the root filesystem size**. I already have a functional root filesystem and am currently manually removing portions and seeing if the root file system will mount. Is there a more logical approach to reducing file system size rather than the current trial and error method  **Updated with additional details**: The original filesystem used on the target is a generic filesystem used across multiple embedded products in our organization. I want to strip down the filesystem to the bare minimum required to run my specific product .i.e IPNetCam. I want to know if there are any profiling methods hat can determine the exact set of files required to boot and run a particular application.

Comment: Filesystem size is probably not a major contributor to boot time.  Also, checking the ability to mount the filesystem says little about if you have the components required to run whatever programs the system needs.  Major things to look at would be if your distribution is packaging heavy libraries you do not need, various extra daemons (you may have an ssh or web server you didn't know about), or even worse, test/demo programs.  Things like busybox often have configuration where you can include/remove various functionality.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The embedded system is fixed functionality (IP netcam) so if I am able to mount the rfs and run the device it should be fine.End users will not modify it once deployed. I am looking for things to remove like you have mentioned. I want to know if there is a structured way I can go about picking only the bare minimum needed for the root file system

Comment: @ChrisStratton The filesystem will be flashed in NAND , copied to RAM and mounted in the device. So by reducing the total root file system size we can reduce the time it takes for the device to boot (By boot time I mean kernel comes up, app starts running and IPNetcam is ready to use)

Comment: @Badria - unless you have a very very slow NAND inteface, that's likely not a significant amount of time compared to other sources of boot time.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the part "currently manually removing portions and seeing if the root file system will mount". Are you saying that you are chopping off parts of the end of a file system image to shrink it? That is not a good idea, it is likely to cause silent corruption ("mount" may not detect anything wrong). You need to shrink the file system by using a tool for that purpose. For ext2/3/4, this describes how: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reduce_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html

Comment: @MatsEkberg I am not chopping the end of file system. I am removing things I think are not required like some libs, some files etc and recreating the file system image and seeing if it will mount. If I removed a file required for operation of the end system I undo.I am doing this by trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to list the files used by your OS and its application would be to:

- turn on the atime flag on your file system (if not yet set)
- reboot
- after your application has run long enough, use atime to find out what files have been accessed after the last boot:

---

```
# last reboot | head -1
reboot   system boot  2.6.35-30-generi Sun May 20 10:08 - 10:48  (00:40)
# touch -d "2012-05-20 10:07" /tmp/ref
# find / -xdev -anewer /tmp/ref > /tmp/usedFiles
```

Of course, this method is ignoring files not accessed in your sample run but still necessary in infrequent or exceptional situations. You will also need to add files directly read by the boot loader or the OS in early stages when the file system is accessed in read-only mode.

Comment: Also, no need to spawn a secondary process (`head`, in this case). You can simply run:
`last reboot -1`

Comment: `last -1 reboot` would still output two extra lines so I prefer keeping the only one I'm interested in with `head -1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not already doing so, you should use a compressed file system such as [SquashFS](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/). That will drastically reduce the footprint of your boot image.